# Convert .data file from Merkury Innovations (Geeni) camera's SD card into a playable format

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, sd-card, camera

So my parents bought a cheap security cam, Merkury Innovations 720p to put up around the house. They had some issues and now need to get all the footage from the last 3 days (which is fine because it saves for the last 7 days) but there is no way to get it out of the app. The only way to "record" it is by doing the playback feature in the app and pressing the **Record** button which will record it to your phones storage while you are watching it, which means if we need 3 days worth of video and audio, it will take 3 days to **Record** it which isn't feasible.

I unplugged the camera and loaded the contents of the micro sd card onto my harddrive and its in the following format: */record/2023/08/26/0/00000.data* in the format */record/{year}/{month}/{day}/{hour}/*.data.* Each specific date also has a {date}.index file like */record/2023/08/26/20230806.index* but no clue what this is.

It looks like each .data file represents 60minutes of recording as its pretty constant through the SD card. However this ".data" file is in some proprietary format that is only readable by the app. I have spent hours browsing forums and reviews trying to find a way to retrieve this information as its very important and dear to my family. If I had known ahead of time I would've recommended a camera that wrote in a readable format to the SD card instead of this one.

My search has led me down the following rabbit holes. First I checked [Amazon reviews](https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/Tx1QA4K5F3SABDJ/ref=ask_ql_ql_al_hza) and that didn't really help, I found an answer there from the seller stating that the file stored on the SD card has some sort of encryption and is only playable on the app.

After that reported no luck, I found another [post here](https://superuser.com/questions/1487108/how-to-play-data-files-from-security-camera-sd-card) which covered some potential options, the most promising one being ffmpeg. I did manage to find a ffmpeg command that worked, however I was only able to get the video, which is great but the most valuable thing is the audio here containing last words of a family member. I have tried numerous different video conversion apps trying to get this data out and no matter what I do I can't get both video and audio out. I think it is because this ".data" file doesn't have an audio stream visible in ffprobe or MediaInfo.

Here below is the "MediaInfo" of that .data file and I notice that there isn't a audio stream which I have no idea why because if you view it in the app it is there. There is no other storage on the device besides the SD card, and I don't see any other files on the SD card besides these .data files. [image]

Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated, my absolute last resort is setting up an Android emulator on a machine and installing the app and running it on there to record it, which is something that I would really like to avoid. **I feel like I am close with the fact I am able to get the video, but I just need a way to find and pull the audio stream out.**

EDIT: I was asked to [provide some example files to take a look at, they can be found here](https://siglerdev.us/downloads/Camera%20SD%20Card%20files%2008242023_12AM.zip). I included the files individually and also zipped, the file paths for the two files are below. I specifically picked the one at 12AM  (folder "00") because it has sound from the TV and no PII in it from viewing it in the app.

\record\2023\08\24\20230824.index - index file

\record\2023\08\24\00\000001.data - data file

Comment: Very long shot, but have you tried VLC?

Comment: is it possible that the audio stream is in a different file?

Comment: best would be to share a sample .data file + corresponding .index file.

Comment: @davidgo Yeah I tried VLC, it does this weird buffer where the slider bounces back and forth and never loads the video (in the .data format or if I change extension to .mp4) it only becomes playable if I ffmpeg into an mp4.

Comment: @Mokubai I thought so as well, but I didn't find any other file types or files in the SD card, I think its somehow embedded inside the .data file and only playable by the app.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen What would be the best way to share the files here? The .data is a 200MB file, just upload it online and share a link?

Comment: Yes, but only if you're comfortable with it. Otherwise try a service like restore.media or similar.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I edited the original post to include it, I didn't want to deal with having any one in the video for privacy reasons so I have a 1 hour snippet where the TV is on off to the side so there's definitely audio. Please let me know if you have any ideas, thank you so much!

Comment: Did you solve this?  I tried to look at the data you uploaded but got the message that the data I was looking for has been deleted.

Comment: I get the deleted message too.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I re-uploaded it to a personal site. Sorry for the delayed responses, it has just the zip of the .index file and the .data file. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @davidgo No i haven't solved it yet, not sure why that file.io site took it down but it was set to expire after 2 weeks (the default), I ended up uploading to my site in a zip file, please check the original post again. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I got the file, but so far no luck getting audio out of it.

Comment: Same. Video but no audio.

Comment: I don't see any other files/folders on the SD card, I have the camera set up to only record to the SD card with it overwriting the oldest file (so the SD card is practically full when viewing in Windows explorer). I'll try turning on hidden files/folders in explorer but I doubt that will make a difference, is there anything else I can provide to help?